# Can't get the desired output in the official MySQL connector

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-connector

I use Python to connect to MariaDB. I recently switched from the PyMySQL to the native connector from [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html) and I can't get to work this simple code:

```
a = mysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', db='db', passwd='1337')
b = a.cursor()
b.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts', multi=True)
b.execute('SELECT * FROM profile', multi=True)
print(b.fetchall())
a.commit()
```

I thought it would print all the rows from the `profile` table, but for some reason it does not, and exits with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<file>", line 142, in <module>
    print(b.fetchall())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 676, in fetchall
    raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

Comment: If you're only executing one query at a time, you don't need the `multi=True`. I don't see why you're executing two separate queries, though. If you just want the `profile` table, then why are you `SELECT`ing from the `accounts` table as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the `multi=True` parameter, the `cursor.execute()` method returns an iterable object which you should use to get the results. There's an example of usage in [section 8.3.4 of the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/myconnpy_MySQLCursor_execute.html).

However, you only need to use that if you intend to execute multiple statements in a single query, such as...

```
iterable = b.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts; SELECT * FROM profile', multi=True)
for item in iterable:
    print(item.fetchall())
```

...although this is a non-standard extension to [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

If you only need to execute a single query, then it's much simpler to omit the `multi` argument...

```
b.execute('SELECT * FROM profile')
print(b.fetchall())
```

...which is compliant with PEP 249.